# Superposition principle is not synonymous of linearity?

Tags: linear-algebra, definition

In linear differential equations

models are said to be linear iff superposition holds,
f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y) and cf(x) = f(cx)

but what about a single linear variable equation?

f(x) = m * x + h,

f(x+y) != f(x) + f(y)
cf(x) != f(cx), because the **h** it will have a bias.

A simple linear relation doesn't satisfy superposition.

Comment: Its called a linear theory because we can take the linear combinations of the solutions as a single solution. Besides the functions taken as solutions to ODE's tend not to be linear functions themselves (like exponentials or sinusoids). Another thing to note is that your example $f(x) + f(y) = mx+h + my+h = m(x+y) + 2 h \neq f(x+y)$

Comment: right, edited, so, f(x) = mx+h, a bold linear function doesn't hold superposition. (but holds for $\Delta$f)

Answer (score 1):

Here linear is used in two different ways. The function
$$f(x)=ax+b$$
is linear in the sense that it is a polynomial function of degree $1$. As you have noted, though, it doesn't exhibit linearity. This function is only linear in the additive sense if $b=0$. When $b\neq 0$, it is a linear function composed with a translation, which is called an *affine function*.